# Filter data based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists

I have a table like below. I need to find out the employes who have rank R1 but never have rank C1 and C2.

```
Id  ECode Name Rank
1   EMP1    AA  R1
2   EMP2    BB  R1
3   EMP1    AA  R2
4   EMP1    AA  C1
5   EMP1    AA  C2
6   EMP1    AA  C3
7   EMP2    BB  C4
8   EMP2    BB  C5
9   EMP3    CC  R1
10  EMP3    CC  C1
11  EMP3    CC  C2
12  EMP3    CC  C4
13  EMP4    DD  R1
14  EMP4    DD  C3
```

Comment: People are often careless about the use of "and" (they often mean "or"), so I'll ask: You want to exclude an employee if they ever have the rank C1 **or** C2 (or possibly both), or do you want to exclude an employee only if they have BOTH the rank C1 AND the rank C2 (in a different row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select *
  from mytable t
 where t.rank = 'R1' 
   and not exists ( select ECode from mytable where ECode = t.ecode and  rank in ('C1','C2') );
```

Comment: I used this one. working perfectly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM EMPLOYES  A
 WHERE RANK = 'R1'
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM EMPLOYES  B
                   WHERE B.ECODE = A.ECODE
                     AND RANK IN ('C1','C2')
                     AND ROWNUM = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses aggregation by employee:

```
SELECT ECode, Name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ECode, Name
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN Rank = 'R1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN Rank IN ('C1', 'C2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
SELECT ecode, name
FROM t
WHERE rank IN ('R1', 'C1', 'C2')
GROUP BY ecode, name
HAVING MIN(rank) = MAX(rank) AND MAX(rank) = 'R1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select * 
from table t 
where exists (select 1 from table where ECode = t.ECode and Rank = 'R1') AND 
      not exists (select 1 from table where ECode = t.ECode and Rank IN ('C1', 'C2'))
```

Comment: Are you the same Yogesh Sharma that we see every day?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen.. Yes as because i am unable to access my own account. Hence, i have created this one as guest account.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from (tablename)
where Rank = 'R1'
and Rank not in (Select Rank from (tablename)
where Rank = 'C1' 
or Rank = 'C2')
```

Comment: This won't work and in fact makes no sense because if the rank is `R1` then by definition is won't match your two `LIKE` conditions.

Comment: Also why did you put `(` and `)` around tablename -- are you trying to protect it from something?  evaluate it first?